# Issues reading string input in Java with scanner class

Tags: java

I'm pretty much a complete newbie when it comes to Java. I've dabbled a bit in python and VB.net, and that's about it.

I'm trying to write a program in java that literally reads the user's input and displays it back to them with this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputTesting
{   
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );

        String str1;

        System.out.println("Input string: ");

        str1 = input.nextString();

        System.out.println( str1 );
    }
}
```

And I get the error:

```
InputTesting.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        str1 = input.nextString();
                    ^
  symbol:   method nextString()
  location: variable input of type Scanner
1 error
```

Can someone tell what why it's not compiling? Thanks!

Comment: Learning to read compile errors will help you immensely. This is literally telling you that scanner has no method nextString. At that point, if you shoot on over to the java API for scanner you can look for the method you need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
input.nextString();
```

There is no method called `nextString` in the `Scanner` class. That's why you're getting the error `cannot find symbol`.

Try

```
input.nextLine(); // If you're expecting the user to hit enter when done.
input.next(); // Just another option.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputTesting
{   
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );

         String str1;

        System.out.println("Input string: ");

            str1 = input.next();

        System.out.println( str1 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use one of `input.nextXXX()` as detailed in [Scanner javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). to resolve compiler error

in your case

you may use `input.nextLine();` get entire line of text.

By Default whitespace delimiter used by a scanner. However If you need to scan sequence of inputs separated by a delimiter `useDelimiter` can be used to set regex delim

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);) {
        input.useDelimiter(";");
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String next = input.next();
            if ("DONE".equals(next)) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Token:" + next);
        }
    }
}
```

Input

```
1a;2b;3c;4d;5e;DONE;
```

Output

```
Token:1a
Token:2b
Token:3c
Token:4d
Token:5e
```

Just be cautious while scanning decimal and signed numbers as scanning is `Locale` Dependent

Answer (score 0):

You need to rather use method `nextLine()`. This methods prints entire line. By using `next()` it will print only one word in your sentence.

Answer (score 0):

// That's how i managed solution for input a string

import java.util.Scanner;
public class PalindromeWord {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    //System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    


     String S = input.next(); 
     String reverseStr = "";
    
    int strLength = S.length();

    for (int i = (strLength - 1); i >=0; --i) {
      reverseStr = reverseStr + S.charAt(i);
    }

    if (S.equals(reverseStr)) {
      System.out.println("Yes");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("No");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please, format your answer properly with your code block